# KnockoutJS - Select Menu Multiple Options

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have 2 select menus. One with single select, the other multiple option select.

When the first one is selected, it should then automatically select those related options in the 2nd menu.

So for example, if "*ManualItems*" is selected, it should then mark "*Analyst*" and "*Supervisor*" as selected in the 2nd select menu.

Neither menu is binding successfully so I am not sure what I am missing.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="taskName">Edit Existing Task</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="taskNameSelect"
            data-bind="options: tasks,
                                   optionsText: 'TaskName',
                                   value: currentTask,
                                   optionsCaption: 'Select Task...'"></select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="editApprovalLevelList">Select Approval Levels</label>
  <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="editApprovalLevelList"
          data-bind="options: availableApprovalLevels,
                     selectedOptions: userSelectedApprovalLevels,
                     optionsText: 'ApprovalLevelName',
                     optionsvalue: 'ApprovalLevelName'"></select>
</div>
```

.

```
var viewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;

    // variables
    self.currentTask = ko.observable();
    self.userSelectedApprovalLevels = ko.observable[];

    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([
    {TaskID: 1, TaskName: "ManualItems", ApprovalLevels:[{"ApprovalID": 1},{"ApprovalID": 2}]},
    {TaskID: 1, TaskName: "Trades", ApprovalLevels:[{"ApprovalID": 2}]},
    {TaskID: 1, TaskName: "Positions", ApprovalLevels:[{"ApprovalID": 1},{"ApprovalID": 3}]},
    ]);

    self.availableApprovalLevels = ko.observableArray([
        {ApprovalID: 1, ApprovalLevelName: "Analyst"},
      {ApprovalID: 2, ApprovalLevelName: "Supervisor"},
      {ApprovalID: 3, ApprovalLevelName: "Manager"}
    ]);

      self.currentTask.subscribe(function (task) {
        var matchingApprovalLevel = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.availableApprovalLevels(), function (approvalLevel) {
            return approvalLevel.ApprovalID === task.ApprovalID;
        });
        self.userSelectedApprovalLevels(matchingApprovalLevel);
    });      

};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upmad7s8/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of other issues in your example, but ignoring those, you should be generating an array of selected values if you want the multi selection to work.  You originally was selecting approval levels based on the task's `ApprovalID`. But a task doesn't have an approval id, it has an array of approval levels.

```
self.currentTask.subscribe(function (task) {
    var selected = ko.utils.arrayMap(task.ApprovalLevels, function(a) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.availableApprovalLevels(), function (ta) {
            return a.ApprovalID === ta.ApprovalID;
        });
    });
    self.userSelectedApprovalLevels(selected);
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upmad7s8/5/)